# Searching in a column in datatable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datatables

I'm new to Angular, I have a datatable that displays employee data, everything is working fine except that whenever I search in the name field, no data is displaying while searching unless I hit the space key then backspace, otherwise the table just shows that there is no data displayed, although in the console it shows that data exists from the input that I typed.
So in order to display data from searching, I have to type the name then space then backspace, hope I've made it clear, Your assistance is much appreciated.

employees.component.html

```
<table id="myTable" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" 
 [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border 
  hover stripe">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="border-left" translate>employees.name<i class="fas fa- 
       search"
       10px 0px 10px;" (click)="filterByName()"></i><input type="text" 
       [formControl]="employeeFilterCtrl" id="myId" style="z-index: 9999; 
       display: none;"/></th>
      <th class="border-center" translate>employees.status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of filteredEmployees | async">
    <tr *ngFor="let employeeStatus of item.employeeJobStatuses">
      <td>{{ item.firstName_FL + ' ' + item.secondName_FL + ' ' + 
         item.lastName_FL + ' ' + 
       item.familyName_FL }}</td>
      <td>{{ employeeStatus.status | translate }}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
  </tbody>
```

employees.component.ts

```
filterByName(){
document.querySelector('#myId').setAttribute('style', 'display: unset);
}
search() {
    if (!this.employees) {
        return
    }
    let search = this.employeeFilterCtrl.value;
    if (!search) {
        this.filteredEmployees.next(this.employees.slice());
        console.log(this.filteredEmployees.next(this.employees.slice()))
        return;
    } else {
        search = search.toLowerCase();
    }
    this.filteredEmployees.next(
        this.employees.filter(employee => 
       employee.firstName_FL.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1)
    );
    console.log(this.employees.filter(department =>
        department.firstName_FL.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1))
}

getActiveEmployees(){
this.loading = true;
this.restService.GetActiveEmployees().subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.employees = res.data.employees;
  console.log(this.employees)
  const maw = JSON.stringify(this.employees)
  this.jsonObj = JSON.parse(maw);
  this.Employee.setValue(this.employees[5]);
  this.filteredEmployees.next(this.employees.slice());
  this.employeeFilterCtrl.valueChanges
  .pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.search();
  });
  if (this.isDtInitialized) {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
      dtInstance.destroy();
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
  } else {
    this.isDtInitialized = true
    this.dtTrigger.next();
  }
  this.loading = false;
 })
 }
```

Comment: I went through this link " http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/with-options "                  & in search field I just entered names & corresponding records automatically came. So in your case it's not happening like that? Could you please tell why you are adding custom code?

Comment: Yes, that's the link that I used when building the datatable, however the problem is with the behavior of the table when filtering

Comment: I'm adding custom code because I have a more complex design that just adding a footer, also when I tried the code in your link it came up with an error next is not a function

Comment: In your html you are calling filterbyname(on click)? But you mentioned search method code. From where you are calling search method? Could you please provide any stackblitz with sample data?

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI I have updated my code now it should be more clear, thanks in advance.